# Web api development time Authorization attribute disable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am using authorized controller actions and some of them are role based.

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "SuperUsers")]
    public class UserGroupController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly MyContext context = new MyContext();

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
        {
           .......
        }
    }
```

When I want to use this controller, my request returns 401 unauthorized messsage.

So I have created an Authrization attribute to disable it like this:

```
public class DevelopmentAuthorizationFilter:AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        return actionContext.Request.RequestUri.IsLoopback || base.IsAuthorized(actionContext);
    }
}
```

And I added it to HttpConfiguration filters.

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
        .............
        configuration.Filters.Add(new DevelopmentAuthorizationFilter());
    }
```

But it does not work. How can I solve this?

Comment: Would you like to bypass the authorization-attribute for development purposes or what's your intention?

Answer (score 0):

You applied two authorization filters to controller. `DevelopmentAuthorizationFilter` (which is passed) on global level and `AuthorizeAttribute` (which is not passed) on controller level. So using only `DevelopmentAuthorizationFilter` on controller level should fix the problem.

```
[DevelopmentAuthorizationFilter(Roles = "SuperUsers")]
public class UserGroupController : ApiController
{

}
```